# How do I randomly group together adjacent cells in a 2 dimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am making a [KenKen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KenKen) generator in JavaScript. For this, I need to create a Latin square with "cages" that will later have operands in them. I have been following some guidance from [a paper by Tom Davis](http://www.geometer.org/mathcircles/kenken.pdf), and he describes how to create the cages (9.4, page 21):

> First, [my algorithm] generates a random Latin square. It then generates cages by randomly picking adjacent squares and combining them into cages with some restrictions.

I already have the code to generate a random Latin square, but I seem to be stumped on how to combine adjacent cells. I tried something myself, as you can see below, but the more I wrote, the less sure I felt and the messier and more unmaintainable the code became.

My question is, how do I do this efficiently?

```
/**
 * Create the cages for operations to go in
 */
createCages(){
  var cages = []; // list of all cages

  // keep track of what cells are in what cages 
  // (the contents of this will be changed later, we just clone the grid so it has the same structure)
  var cagesByCell = this.clone(this.grid); 

  // every cell starts out as its own cage
  for (let y = 0; y < this.size; y++){
    for (let x = 0; x < this.size; x++){
      let newCage = [[y,x]];
      cages.push(newCage);
      cagesByCell[y][x] = newCage;
    }
  }

  // 
  let cells = this.getCellPositions();
  for (let i = 0; i < this.size; i++){
    // get random cell
    let cell = cells[i];
    let y = cell[0];
    let x = cell[1];

    // pick a random adjacent neighor to that cell
    let other;
    while (other == undefined){
      let neighor = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
      switch (neighor){
        case 0: if (y > 0)           {other = [y-1, x]} break; // NORTH
        case 1: if (x < this.size-1) {other = [y, x+1]} break; // EAST
        case 2: if (y < this.size-1) {other = [y+1, x]} break; // SOUTH
        case 3: if (x > 0)           {other = [y, x-1]} break; // WEST
      }
    }
    let y1 = other[0];
    let x1 = other[1];

    // merge their cages
    let cageNum = cages.indexOf(cagesByCell[y][x]);
    let cageNum1 = cages.indexOf(cagesByCell[y1][x1]);
    let cage = cages[cageNum];
    let cage1 = cages[cageNum1];
    for (let i = 0; i < cage1.length; i++){
      cage.push(cage1[i])
    }

    cages.splice(cageNum1, 1);
  }
  console.log(cages)
}
```

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, please post your full code on [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/) and comment a link to it. I would like to try some things out with it. Thank you.